# Javascript/Jquery check my if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm working with someone else's code trying to get an alert to come up to notify the user if the operation was unsuccessful. I put an "if (true)" statement in front of the function and then an "else" statement after the function, thinking that IF the function ran successfully, it would alert the user with "success" otherwise it would alert "operation failed". Did I do this right? I'm completely new to Javascript.

```
 $("#assignBtn").on("click", function () {if(true){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_parse_checklist/assign_checklist',
        data: {
            username: $("#assignChecklistTo").val(),
            id: $clientSelect.val()
        },
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        complete: function () {
            alert("Success!");
        }
    });}
    else {alert("Operation unsuccessful...")}
});
```

Comment: `if(true)` will always be true...

Comment: Are you trying to determine whether the AJAX call is successful?

Comment: You have `complete` mapped to a callback that runs `alert(success)`, now just map `error` to a callback that runs `alert('error')`. Read more about jQuery's AJAX function [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Ah. AJAX. I was going to get to that after Javascript. Thank you very much.

Comment: `alert` is not a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of if/else you can use ajax methods:

```
success: function(data) {
    // success
},
error: function(data) {
    // error
}
```

Comment: It doesn't show both after fixing it, but it always reports an error. I can see the data going into my SQL database, so it shouldn't be reporting an error.